# Does the IBM SPSS file format support datetime variables with timezone offset?

Tags: datetime, timezone, spss

I'm working on data from a database with a timestamp column (including timezone offset), with multiple timezone offsets. Is it possible in SPSS to keep the offset information using a particular variable/data type?

I know about the general principle of converting all timestamps to a particular, common timezone — like UTC — but would like to know if SPSS supports date/time types with timezone information.

I have studied the [SPSS Documentation about Date and Time Formats](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spss-statistics/28.0.0?topic=formats-date-time), but haven't seen any information about supporting timezones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that SPSS internally stores the datetime value as a numerical value (which is the number of seconds since the epoch, midnight, Oct. 14, 1582) with no meta information, there is no way to keep time zones with the value.

You will therefore need to have another variable (i.e., column) containing the time zone information.